# Как закодировать русские символы в строке?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы на входе была например такая строка:

```
<html props="фывп"></html>
```

а на выходе это

```
<html props="&#1092;&#1099;&#1074;&#1087;"></html>
```

Как такое можно сделать не трогая при этом другие элементы строки? Не важно в какую кодировку, главное чтобы потом можно было декодировать

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `encodeURI` для кодировки и `decodeURI` для декодировки

```js
var str = "фывп";

console.log(encodeURI(str));
console.log(decodeURI(encodeURI(str)));
```

Comment: В таком случае получится:
'%3Chtml%20props=%22%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BF%22%3E%3C/html%3E'
Я имею ввиду что строка это "<html props="фывп"></html>"